# A condition using if else statement in php

Tags: php

I have a small problem here.
I need to make a condition in my page, if no data were found in database, a message should be outputted

this is the code

```
foreach ($movies as $movie)
{
    $movie_id = $movie['movie_id'];
    $movie_name = $movie['movie_name'];
    $movie_category = $movie['movie_category'];
    $movie_display = $movie['movie_display'];

    if ($movie_id){
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>' . $movie_name . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $movie_category . '</td>';
        echo '<td align="center">';
        if ($movie_display==1) { echo "YES";} else { echo "NO";} 
        echo '</td>';
        echo '<td align="center">';
        echo "<a href='editmovies.php?movie_id={$movie_id}'>". edit .'</a><br/></td>';
        echo '<td align="center">';
        echo "<a class='delete' href='deletemovie.php?movie_id={$movie_id}'>". delete .'</a><br/></td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }
    else { 
        echo 'no results were found';
    }
}
echo '</table>';
```

Even when the database is empty, no message is delivered and I dont know why.

Thank you

Comment: where is the database code?

Answer (score 3):

Your message is inside your `foreach` loop so if no items are found, that part of the code is never reached.

You need to add an additional check before or after the loop:

```
if (empty($movies))
{
  echo 'no results were found';
}
else
{
  // do you loop
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work just fine.

```
if(count($movies) > 0){
    foreach ($movies as $movie)
        // Do stuff
    }
}
else{
    echo 'No results returned';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're assuming that the array `$movies` will have a `$movie`. You should instead check to see if the array is empty:

```
if( empty($array) ) {
    //Array empty
}
else {
    foreach ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of
`if($movie_id) { ... }` 
try 
`if (!empty($movie_id)) { ... }`